# How to link with libcurl on Pangolin

Tags: 12.04, gcc, curl

Since Pangolin, I can't manage to link any program with libcurl, even the example provided with libcurl themselves.

I have installed libcurl:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

Then as the README says in /usr/share/doc/libcurl4-gnutls-dev/examples I tried compiling the simplest program in the examples (copied it to /tmp before to avoid write access issues)

```
`curl-config --cc --cflags --libs` -o simple simple.c
```

And then I get:

```
simple.c:(.text+0x99): undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
simple.c:(.text+0xc6): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
simple.c:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
simple.c:(.text+0xe1): undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It worked like a charm with 10.04, but now it does not anymore on 12.04.

Any idea on how to link sucessfuly with libcurl in 12.04?

Should I report to launchpad, as obviously, there is something broken, either in the libraries installation, or at least in the documentation?

It could be a issue with new multiarch, something I do wrong on the command line related to that new multiarch, or the libs were not installed in the directories expected by multiarch?

Answer (score 2):

Answered by launchpad

The documentation in /usr/share/doc/libcurl4-gnutls-dev/html/curl-config.html is indead wrong, and thus this is a documentation bug.

Instead or reading on line 88:

```
`curl-config --cc --cflags --libs` -o example example.c
```

it should read

```
`curl-config --cc --cflags` -o example example.c `curl-config --libs`
```

This places the shared libraries AFTER the object we want to link, and now it works.